# file not found error in chrome for html code

Tags: html, google-chrome, file-not-found

I have been trying to open html file from my desktop folder using chrome. It shows file_not_found it may be deleted or moved. But same is getting open in Edge browser. I'm using windows 10. code written in VS Code editor. Need help. I'm a beginner in programming language.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

Install a live-server extension in VS code then you can serve your page from there
You can download from the extensions tab by searching live Server by `ritwickdey` or
use this link https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer